# How to remove "\u0006" from a string? (Replace() method seems not to replace anything)

Tags: c#, string, ascii

I imagine this being a very weird question:
I'm working in C#, and I have a string, containing exactly one character, ASCII-code 6.

You can see this in the Watch-window:

```
current "\u0006"    string
```

Now I have this piece of code:

```
if (current.IndexOf("\u0006") != -1)
    current.Replace("\u0006",string.Empty);
if (current != "") // <= I am here and 'current' still is just "\u0006"
```

My code went into the `if`-clause, so the `"\u0006"` is recognised, but for some reason it doesn't get removed.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're throwing away the result of the `Replace` call. Asign the result back to the variable: `current = current.Replace("\u0006",string.Empty);`.

Comment: Are you expecting `current.Replace(...)` to cause `current` to have a different value? Why? What happened when you tried reading the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `string` is immutable it is not being changed. When calling `Replace`, it returns a new `string` but doesn't update the current one.

```
current = current.Replace("\u0006",string.Empty);
```